# R: How to multiply a factor of numbers by a constant

Tags: r

After running a knn model as follows:
`pred_norm <- knn(train_norm, test_norm, cl = train_norm$ef_scale, k = k)`

I am trying to create a table of my output results like this:
`tab_norm <- table(pred_norm, 5*test_norm$ef_scale)`

I multiplied 5* the test_norm because the data was normalized before the knn, and the original data for that column were the integers 0-5. This produced this table:

```
pred_norm    0    1    2    3    4    5
      0   5249    0    0    0    0    0
      0.2   38 3897  136    1    0    0
      0.4    0    0 1523  257    1    0
      0.6    0    0    0  211   72    0
      0.8    0    0    0    0    5    6
      1      0    0    0    0    0    0
```

This converted the normalized 0, 0.2, ..., 1 back to the original 0-5, but when I tried multiplying the pred_norm using 5* in the same way, I got this warning message:

> In Ops.factor(5, pred_norm) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors.

I tried using
`pred_norm <- as.numeric(pred_norm)`
to convert it an integer, and it let me convert the numbers, but it dropped the 0 and moved all the lines up one, combining the 4 and 5 into one row. The same thing happened when I tried using
`pred_norm <- as.integer(pred_norm)`

Both of those gave tables that looked like this:

```
pred_norm    0    1    2    3    4    5
        1 5249    0    0    0    0    0
        2   38 3897  136    1    0    0
        3    0    0 1523  257    1    0
        4    0    0    0  211   72    0
        5    0    0    0    0    5    6
```

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can convert pred_norm so that it will be 0-5 instead of decimals from 0-1 or integers from 1-5?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `as.character` + `as.numeric` like below

```
df$pred_norm <- as.numeric(as.character(df$pred_norm))*5
```

or `levels` + `as.numeric`

```
df$pred_norm <- as.numeric(levels(df$pred_norm)[df$pred_norm])*5
```

Comment: I tried both of these. While these did preserve the leading 0 as I was hoping, they both dropped the 5 at the end. My table still has 5 rows instead of 6, but now they are numbered 0-4 and not 1-5 and they need to be 0-5 like they are originally.